# Allow only one thread at the time to use an object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass{

    private List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public List<Integer> getInts(){
        return ints;
    }

    public synchronized void doAction(){ 
        //Do some with the list
    }
}
```

I need to allow only one thread at the time having acces to the `List`. I would do that as follows:

```
public class MyClass{

    private List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private static final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);

    public List<Integer> getInts(){
        s.acquire();
        return ints;
    }

    public void release(){
        s.release();
    }

    public synchronized void doAction(){ 
        s.acquire();
        //Do some with the list
        s.release();
    }
}
```

But the implementaion is obviously not reliable, because if the client request the `List` through the getter for adding some elements into it and forget to call `release()` we'll get into troubles if try to invoke the `doAction` method.

What is the solution for the problem?

Comment: Kayaman has the right answer here, but also, in the future, if you think you want to use a `Semaphore` in this way, consider using a `java.util.concurrent.Lock` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't allow the client to get the reference. Put all the methods that work on the list to `MyClass` and synchronize them.

You can allow the users to get a snapshot copy of the list however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a synchronized list:

```
private List<Integer> ints = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

Comment: But that won't provide synchronization over iteration for example.

Comment: @Kayaman You mean if we some thread is changing the list while another one is printing its content through iteration we'll get not exactly what we wanted...

Comment: Exactly. You would then have to trust that any iterating thread would synchronize on the list.

Comment: When working with threads and lists it's always recommended to synchronize on the list.
If you want provide an "idiot proof" API you'll have to wrap all calls like @Kayaman said.

Comment: BTW, inspite of throwing ConcurrentModificationException for the mst of collection implementation we can't rely on that and just wrap the code in try-catch, right?

Comment: @user3663882 No, ConcurrentModificationException shouldn't be caught, because it means the code is broken (iterating and modifying the collection at the same time). You can get that even if you only have a single thread.

Comment: What you say is true, but the truth of it does not make it good advice.  The OP's class is special because all of its state is contained in a single other object.  Using a synchronized list would _not_ make `MyClass` thread-safe if `MyClass` had other fields with contents that relate to the contents of the list.  A noob who has to ask, "is this thread safe" probably does not appreciate that thread-safety is not composable:  building a class or a program entirely out of thread safe objects will not make the class or the program thread safe.